# Node js server not responding

Tags: node.js, unix, networking, express

I have a Node.js API on which I have been working for a while, and I am trying to deploy it on my server.

Locally, I have been able to run it without any problem, with node version `v0.10.32`

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp   0   0  0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      19091/nginx
tcp   0   0  0.0.0.0:3333       0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      12594/node
tcp   0   0  127.0.0.1:27017    0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      22091/mongod
```

I upload the project on my server (same node version), no error is shown in the logs, the process seems to listen on port 3333. But when I do `domain.name:3333`, I get no answer. As you can see above, the node process is listening on `0.0.0.0` interface, so it doesn't seem to be the problem.

`domain.name:80` works fine, nginx is well responding.

```
$ nmap domain.name
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
3333/tcp open  dec-notes
$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**The nmap from the outside (my personal computer) is not displaying the port 3333 though**

Do anyone know where the problem is from?

Comment: I guess the server's firewall settings?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Nope, if you look at the iptables, there's absolutely no rule, so that means it accepts everything. But I managed to resolve it, it was a simple oversight. If you're interested, I posted an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what the problem was.

I had to change bind settings in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

It was listening on `127.0.0.1` only. To resolve this problem, just change the following line:

```
listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
```

to

```
listen-on { any; };
```